# Show that every point is an extreme point of the given convex set

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

> Show that for any  $a,b \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$  every point
> $p=\begin{pmatrix} s\\  t \end{pmatrix}$  with property
> $\frac{s^2}{a^2}+\frac{t^2}{b^2}=1$  is an extreme point of the convex
> set  $E(a,b)=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} x_1\\  x_2 \end{pmatrix} \in
> \mathbb{R}^2 \, \Bigg\vert \, \frac{x_1^2}{a^2}+\frac{x_2^2}{b^2} \leq
> 1\right\}$

This is a task from an old exam but I like to know how it's solved and I'm very unsure about my solution:

So the extreme point of a strictly convex function on a convex set is always found at one of the extreme points of the set.

Luckily we already know that $E(a,b)$ is a convex set. Now what needs to be shown is that $\frac{s^2}{a^2}+\frac{t^2}{b^2}=1$ is strictly convex. It is strictly convex if its Hessian matrix is positive definite. So we need to calculate the Hessian matrix and show it's positive definite:

Here is the part I'm not sure about, the Hessian matrix should be $\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{2}{a^2}+\frac{t^2}{b^2}-1 & \frac{2s}{a^2}+\frac{2t}{b^2}-1\\ 
\frac{2s}{a^2}+\frac{2t}{b^2}-1 & \frac{s^2}{a^2}+\frac{2}{b^2}-1
\end{pmatrix}$ and it's positive definite if all its eigenvalues are greater than zero (because it's a symmetric matrix it's enough to check only this).

But here I have  huge problem because it's too complicated to determine the eigenvalues and it also doesn't really seem to be greater than zero anyway because $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$...? : /

Maybe there is another better way of doing it?

Comment: The question does not mention convex functions. In your attempt at a solution you seem to be trying to show that the function $f$ given by $f(s,t)=s^2/a^2+t^2/b^2-1$ is a strictly convex function (which is not what you are required to do). In doing so, you have also calculated the second derivatives incorrectly. (The Hessian of $f$ is actually $\begin{pmatrix}2/a^2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2/b^2\end{pmatrix}$. It is easily seen that this is positive definite by direct application of the definition or because $2/a^2>0$ and the determinant is positive).

Comment: This follows easily from strict convexity of $x \to x^2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $(x,y)\in E$, 
$$ 0\le \frac{(x-s)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y-t)^2}{b^2}=\underbrace{\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}}_{\le 1}+\underbrace{\frac{s^2}{a^2}+\frac{t^2}{b^2}}_{=1}-2\frac{xs}{a^2}-2\frac{yt}{b^2}$$
with equality only for $(x,y)=(s,t)$.
Hence
$$ \frac s{a^2}\cdot x+\frac t{b^2}\cdot y\le 1$$with equality only for $(x,y)=(s,t)$.
We conclude that $E$ is contained in one of the closed half planes given by the line given with the equation $\frac s{a^2}\cdot x+\frac t{b^2}\cdot y=1$ and that $(s,t)$ is the only point of $E$ on that line.